# Footnote separator for wrapped footnote

Tags: page-breaking, footnotes, rules

In a text I am writing I have a couple of quite long footnotes which start on one page and continue on the next one. In order to comply with style requirements the line separating the body text and the footnotes has to extend over the full width of the text if such a footnote begins there (and does not end on this page). Is there a way (e.g. package with this kind of option) to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [footmisc](http://ctan.org/pkg/footmisc) package and its `splitrule` option.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[splitrule]{footmisc}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1]\footnote{\lipsum*[2]}

\lipsum*[3]\footnote{\lipsum[4-6]\lipsum*[7]}

\end{document}
```

[image]