# Footnote separator for wrapped footnote, problems with Hebrew

Tags: page-breaking, footnotes, rules, hebrew

In a previous question I asked [how to format the footnote separator for wrapped footnotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40036/footnote-separator-for-wrapped-footnote). However, the provided solution unfortunately did not seem to work with my document. Now I have found that just one line prevents the desired result:

```
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
```

(Btw., it does not then matter whether actual Hebrew text occurs or not.)

Does anybody know what causes the problem and how to fix it?

Here is a short example:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper,BCOR10mm,DIV11,toc=flat,final]{scrbook}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[splitrule,hang]{footmisc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=old]{german}
\setotherlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\setotherlanguage[calendar=hebrew,numerals=hebrew]{hebrew}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
%\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Scale=0.9,Script=Hebrew]{Ezra SIL}

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[1]\footnote{\lipsum*[2]}
\lipsum*[3]\footnote{\lipsum[4-6]\lipsum*[7]}
\end{document}
```

Without the line

```
\setotherlanguage[calendar=hebrew,numerals=hebrew]{hebrew}
```

it works perfectly (footnote rule extending over the full text width), otherwise it does not (short footnote rule).

Comment: Works for me, so you'll have to provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: I have just inlcuded a short example (see above).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems (!) to work if one loads `footmisc` *after* issuing `\setotherlanguage{hebrew}`. As I have no clue why this is so, please check your actual document for unintended effects (e.g., whether the `hebrew` features are working as expected).

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper,BCOR10mm,DIV11,toc=flat,final]{scrbook}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=old]{german}
\setotherlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\setotherlanguage[calendar=hebrew,numerals=hebrew]{hebrew}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
%\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Scale=0.9,Script=Hebrew]{Ezra SIL}

\usepackage[splitrule,hang]{footmisc}

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[1]\footnote{\lipsum*[2]}
\lipsum*[3]\footnote{\lipsum[4-6]\lipsum*[7]}
\end{document}
```